# Lazy<T> in the eyes of GC?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, garbage-collection, lazy-evaluation

I was wondering about  : How `GC` sees the `Lazy` object

i.e. :

```
 Lazy<Foo> f = new Lazy<Foo>( );
```

*“Lazy Instantiation” defers creation of an object till the time it is actually accessed*

Does `f` here is a root for the object ? ( meaning he wont be GC'ed ) ?

*( the object is not created by this time... some other code put a value in it later on)*

**or**

GC sees it as un-referenced / un-initialized object - and GCe'd it.

Is it something which I need to take care of ? ( / fear of ?)

```
 public class Foo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } 
        public Foo()
        {
           ID = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think `Lazy<T>` is special in any way regarding the GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` is indeed a reference to the `Lazy<Foo>` instance. The encapsulated `Foo` instance is separate but is made (kept) reachable indirectly.

As long as `f` exists, ie it is a root or it is reachable, the instance won't be (can't be) collected.

There is really nothing special regarding GC here. Don't confuse Lazy with WeakReference.

Comment: “Lazy Instantiation” defers creation of an object till the time it is actually accessed

Comment: @RoyiNamir - and that absolutely doesn't matter. Note that I said "Lazy<Foo> instance", not "Foo instance"

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes but "the object" it refers to is the instance of `T` that the `Lazy<T>` instance will create, not the `Lazy<T>` instance its self.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The thing to be aware of is that `Lazy<T>` isn't special, it's just another generic type so normal GC rules apply.